# Measure memory usage on Apache/Mysql Servers

Tags: mysql, apache, memory-management

I have designed a django app that will plot and export large chunks of data from a mysql/apache setup.

I don't know much about mysql or apache servers. Just enough to get my sites to run on them.

I would like to get a sense of how efficient my site is by determining how much of the apache/mysql resources it eats up with average usage.

The signals stored on the mysql server are between 1-15 MB and I am plotting multiple signals together using numpy and matplotlib. Sometimes the plots hang up on my development server (XAMPP).

Any pointers or suggestions of where to begin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, most complete way to monitor resource usage for MySQL and Apache is with a monitoring tool called [Cacti](http://cacti.net/), with the optional [mysql-cacti-templates](http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cacti-templates/).  The latter templates include graphs for monitoring MySQL and Apache and other servers.

Here's a 2011 presentation on how to install, configure, and use Cacti and the mysql-cacti-templates:

- [Using Cacti To Graph MySQL’s Metrics](http://www.percona.com/redir/files/presentations/Collaborate2011-Using-Cacti-to-Graph-MySQL%27s-Metrics.pdf)

Comment: Agreed - Cacti is the way to go ~ however what is your live environment? I have had a lot of trouble with SNMP [required by Cacti if you are monitoring remotely] & Plesk Virtual machine containers.

Comment: Okay, I haven't tried using it in a Plesk environment, only real Linux hosts or EC2 virtual machines.

Comment: yea - there was something funky about the way MediaTemple deployed/built the kernel for the virtual machines that made SNMP very 'crashy' [nothing to do with Cacti at all!] - I never did figure it out & it was more than a year ago.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into Cacti. It sounds precisely like what I was looking for. Even though it may make no sense I would like to install it on my personal computer to get familiar with it and observe how my site performs. I am not sure what the live environment will be yet. This is a project at work I have undertaken even though I am not in the EIS department per se. So there are details I am not certain of yet.

Comment: That's a great idea, to run it in a development environment so you can try it out.  Cacti gives you *a lot* of information, and it'll take time to learn to use this information effectively to diagnose issues.  It's a professional-strength tool.